# I have question about Django REST Filter ID ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

How Can filter Org.id in Department

simple:

```
 { id: 1, name: ITDepart, description: itdeapart, org: 43}
 { id:2, name: ITDepart, description: itdeapart, org: 42 }
```

I have the following models.py:

Organization model:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_update_image, blank=True, null=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
```

Department model:

```
class Department(models.Model):
   org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True , blank=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have Serializaer:

```
class OrgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   logo = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
   class Meta:
    model = Organization
    fields = [
        'id',  'name', 'description','slug', 'user', 'created_date', 'logo']

class DepartmentSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Department
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'slug' , 'org']
```

I Have Viewset:

```
class OrgViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  authentication_classes = ( TokenAuthentication, )
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
  queryset = Organization.objects.all()
  serializer_class = OrgSerializer

class DepartmentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  authentication_classes = ( TokenAuthentication, )
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
  queryset = Department.objects.all()
  serializer_class = DepartmentSerailizer
  lookup_field = 'pk'
```

Comment: What have you tried and whats not working?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add a default ordering at your model

```
class Organization(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  ....

  class Meta:
     ordering = ['-pk']  # descending
```

or when you filter `Department`

```
qs = Department.objects.filter(...).order_by('org__pk')  # ascending
qs = Department.objects.order_by('org__pk')  # ascending without filter
```

However, ordering django´s default-`pk` doesn´t make sense. If you are using default `PrimaryKey` of django, it has already a ascending ordering by default.